# Python pass tuple in function argument

Tags: python, list, function, tuples, pseudocode

I'm trying to convert this code to python

```
function foo(int[] x, int a, int b, int i, int j) returns int
    int k = j
    int ct = 0
    while k > i-1
        if x[k] <= b and not (x[k] <= a)
            ct = ct + 1
        end
        k = k - 1
    end
    return ct
end

int[] x = [11,10,10,5,10,15,20,10,7,11]
print(foo(x,8,18,3,6))
print(foo(x,10,20,0,9))
print(foo(x,8,18,6,3))
print(foo(x,20,10,0,9))
print(foo(x,6,7,8,8))
```

Convert to python:

```
import pandas as pd

def foo(*x,a,b,i,j):
    ct = 0
    for k in x:
        k = j,
        ct = 0,
        while k > (i-1):
            if x[k] <b and ~(x[k]<=a):
                ct = ct+1
            else:
                k = k-1
    return ct

x = (11,10,10,5,10,15,20,10,7,11)
```

I see that `int[] x` in the first code converted to tuple in python. however I'm stuck with code conversion when passing tuple as argument in the function `foo`.

Comment: I don't know what that first example is, but it's not Java.  There seems to be no Java content to this question.

Comment: You don't need a tuple at all. It's literally the same `x = [...]`

Comment: Why `import pandas as pd`?

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa kind-of convention in the Numpy/SciPy/Jupyter communities. But yeah, in this snippet it's just unused, so doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

end of line `k=j,` you use `','` this code convert `k` to `tuple` and you get `error` in `while k > (i-1)` because you check `tuple` with `int`.

I convert to `python` like below:

```
def foo(x, a, b, i, j):
    k = j
    ct = 0
    while k > i-1:
        if x[k] <= b and not (x[k] <= a):
            ct = ct + 1
        k = k - 1
    return ct

x = (11,10,10,5,10,15,20,10,7,11)

print(foo(x,8,18,3,6))
print(foo(x,10,20,0,9))
print(foo(x,8,18,6,3))
print(foo(x,20,10,0,9))
print(foo(x,6,7,8,8))
```

output:

```
2
4
0
0
1
```

Answer (score 2):

If possible, don't use positional arguments with larger amount of args, instead use kwargs e.g. `foo(x=(1,2,3), a=4, b=5, i=6, j=7)` if you intend to mix them or split it into positionals that are obvious and keyword-based which are not or do not follow the same types (tuple for you) otherwise it's just a matter of time until you swap the args or cause a different type of mess by unpacking the values incorrectly.

For example:

```py
def foo(a: int, b: int, /, values: tuple, length: int = 1, start: int = 0) -> int:
    k = start
    ct = 0
    while k > length - 1:
        if x[k] <= b and not (x[k] <= a):
            ct = ct + 1
        k = k - 1
    return ct
```

`/` splits the positional-only (`a`, `b` because I couldn't really figure out what do they mean in that func) and optionally-keyword arguments which can be passed as positionals as well:

```py
foo(100, 200, values=(9, 8, 7), length=1, start=0)
# 0
foo(100, 200, (9, 8, 7), 1, 0)
# 0
```

Also, Python doesn't enforce the types, so in case your code relies on that, use [`MyPy`](https://pypi.org/project/mypy/) for static analysis and [`ensure.ensure_annotations` decorator](https://pypi.org/project/ensure/) for dynamic one (e.g. in tests or in the app).

Answer (score 1):

You already have an accepted answer, but sometimes it is useful to make everything a bit simpler to understand by using a pythonic way to write the function.

"We want to count (sum up) the number of elements of `x` between indices `i` and `j` which are greater than `a` and less than or equal to `b`", thus becomes:

```
from typing import Sequence

def foo(x: Sequence[int], a: int, b: int, i: int, j: int) -> int:
    return sum(a < v <= b for v in x[i:j])
```